# Alternative to eval when working with functions and expressions provided as strings

Tags: javascript

Before anyone claims this is a duplicate, I have read several questions on here about better alternatives than using eval in JavaScript but none of them applied to my problem.

I am provided strings that contains expressions including function names. For example I might have a string `"getHighest(2)+findMiddle()-2*totalLength(rect1,rect2)"`.

It is very easy for me to call `eval` on this and get a result. My main concern is security since I won't always know where these strings are coming from. Seems I have two options:

1. Continue to use eval but parse the string first to make sure every function call is part of a "safe list" before using eval on the whole string.
2. Don't use eval; but then I'd have to find another way to essentially do the same thing which I suspect would be tricky or instead change the entire nature of my API and how these strings can be created and used.

I am biased toward the first option since using eval on free-form string expressions is super convenient. Can anyone recommend a potentially better solution that I have not thought of, or convince me that I am incorrect with this approach?

Comment: Why why why why why? Why do you need to execute this input?

Comment: You probably can look at this: http://www.sitepoint.com/call-javascript-function-string-without-using-eval/

Comment: @Doorknob I'm using JS in Qt and the functions are actually c++ interop; I'm providing the software with an "embedded" scripting interface which offers the native JS in Qt (so it's not actually embedded) and allows users to script ideas in the app while it is running.

Comment: Then I don't see what's so wrong with `eval`. Aside from social engineering problems, the user can run their own arbitrary code anyway (JS console), so there's no reason not to let them do that in your program either.